# Where in this website could user share a dataset?

Tags: feature-request

Dataset sharing is a very important part of data science, it allows people to solve problems other users have had, allows to know data retrieving techniques, etc.

Just like the dataset tab in kaggle. Where in stackexchange could the users share their datasets? As a question? A section?

Comment: FWIW, you might be interested in our sister site, [opendata.se].

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange is a Q&A community and Dataset Sharing is not in its construction.

Even tough sharing data is relevant to Data Science, in order to keep things organized we have another SE where you can ask about data sources, i.e. (as @Andrew T. put it) our sister site [Open Data Stack Exchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

If you wish to share data, you can Ask a question for where to find that kind of data (if no-one has asked it before) and answer it.

Also, you could ask for a feature to upload files on Open Data, maybe that can be implemented.