# How to share data on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

While working on [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/61510/two-different-results-from-seaborn-and-matplotlib-for-a-kde-plot-whats-the-rea?noredirect=1#comment67071_61510), I asked the submitter for their data, so I could play with it, and the answer was: fine, how can I share it?

I have no idea :p

Looking on SO, I saw [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17675/what-are-some-of-the-best-practices-for-sharing-data-and-models-with-colleagues), but it looks directed for people working together (as opposed to opening it on the Internet for anyone to download), and [this one](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17724/how-should-i-expose-data-from-my-app-for-data-scientists) which is regarding making data available for an app.

[This other question from meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222407/data-upload-sharing-across-stack-exchange-sites) is a request for a feature on Open Data.SO.  It lists some options, but still nothing definitive.

Coming from an IT background, my first reaction for a smaller dataset would be to create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and upload the file.  Not optimal, but it would make the data available.

*How do you share data for a question?*

If possible, different options for small files (several Kb to a few Mb), medium (several Mb to a few Gb) and big (several Gb) would be welcome.

Please note the question is different from [this one](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2446/where-in-this-website-could-user-share-a-dataset), as I'm not asking for sharing within the site, nor where to find a specific dataset.

Comment: So you are asking where to go for free data hosting?

Comment: I think so, @Stephen.  Perhaps specialized free data hosting, perhaps just free data hosting.  By specialized, I mean akin to what github is for code or pastebin for text-only data: is there any service specific for dataset sharing?  If not, what's the best general data sharing service for the purposes of sharing data related to questions in SO?

Comment: You want to be clear whether "share data" means a snippet to reproduce an issue, or the whole dataset. Also whether that is KB, MB, GB, TB, etc. Should it be uncompressed or compressed (and which format)? Also (since people will likely use third-party sites and cloud-hosting) what should be our expectation about ephemerality: is it better to have a small KB snippet that will still be there in 1 month/year/decade, or a 1GB dataset that is inaccessible when the question is answered? And are there issues with licensing/(CC-SA forced) relicensing? (are users aware they're open-sourcing it?)

Comment: If the dataset disappearing makes the question irreproducible, then what's our expectation about MCVE? And if a dataset is proprietary and can't be made public, is it ok for users to post "Contact me if you need access to the data"?

Comment: I am having this exact problem right now. I have a csv that I'm loading into a dataframe that is causing a problem and I know where the problem is (I think) but I can't produce an MRE with a directly created dataframe, the problem disappears.

Comment: @GlenS: why can't you produce an MRE with a directly created dataframe, what is your specific problem (error message? csv load garbled? NAs? wrong types?), and why are you sure the root-cause is the data not the code?

Comment: (Glen's question was different: it was not an MRE simply because the data was posted as an image, not actual data. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))

Comment: @GlenS: no you weren't having that exact problem. [Your question was closed for not containing an MRE because you posted data-as-image, instead of the actual data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657275/getting-valueerror-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-from-seaborn-boxp). If you can edit it to fix that it should get reopened.

Comment: I meant I was having the problem of where to post the data so that it could be downloaded and used in the MRE. Doesn't seem like there's a standard way of doing it and I was looking around when I found this post.

Comment: Often you **don't** need to share your full dataset, to reproduce a minor issue or typo. a) If it's a publicly-available dataset, you don't need to share the data, just share the URL. Just post the `read_csv('http://...')`/`read_html()` pandas command. There are lots of publicly-available datasets, go find one b) If you can reproduce the issue with just a few simplified columns or seeded-random data (which is almost *surely* the case in your question), then just post that data. c) Then you only need to worry about sharing the full dataset (as text, in your question) in a small number of cases.